# selecting images in PDF embedded in html

Tags: html, image, pdf, copy, selection

I embedded a pdf in html using embed tag. I can select text for copying but couldn't select images present in the pdf. What change should I make in this html code?

```
<embed src="sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="800px" height="650px">
```

Answer (score 0):

The way image can be selected is dependent of the pdf browser.

When you embed like that, your web browser will use a plugin to display the pdf. if that plugin don't allow selection and copy of images, then it cannot be done.

If you want to extract image from a pdf, there is tools for that.

Comment: do you know any plugin available for that ?

Comment: Plugins are already intergrated to your browser. That's why you can see pdf in browser. To extract image there is tools like: http://www.rlvision.com/pdfwiz/about.asp

Comment: extracting the image is not a problem. I did that with PHP script. I just need to select images the way I can select text with a mouse click. I can do that normally if opened with adobe reader but when embedded in HTML I couldn't .

Comment: You can try using [adobe reader's plugin](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-browser-plugin-configuration.html) instead of browser native one.